# HTML5 Canvas Arc inactive tab animation issues

Tags: html, animation, canvas, setinterval

I have an animated HTML5 Canvas Arc that isn't a full circle, and changes the angle every 5 seconds via setTimeout. If I leave the tab in the background for a few minutes and come back to it, the arc ends up as a full circle. Keep in mind, the arc must be able to animate while its in the background, so doing a clearInterval on window.blur is not an option.

My guess is too many animation events are being queued up in the background which causes the browser to "overdraw"?

You can see an example of this in action at http://codepen.io/Leland-Kwong/pen/neLtk.

Thanks.